# is the buoybuilder project still alive?

Tags: java

A few years ago I used the excellent Swing development tool buoybuilder.  Today I noticed that their former URL does not work.  Is this project still alive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any actual project URL on Google, and all the download links I can find (for what appears to be the latest version, 1.1.1) were posted November 2007 or earlier. It doesn't look good, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

94-West who wrote BuoyBuilder are still around, try emailing them: support@94-west.com